# Proving the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: Problem]

Hello! Can anyone help me how to proof Schroder-Bernstein Theorem (which is Exercise 8.3.3 above in the picture) using Exercise 8.3.2 in the picture? This is a question from the analysis book written by Tao.

Comment: Did you search the site? There are plenty of proofs of this theorem here already.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I searched this site to find the proof of this theorem. However, the proofs are usually the same with the proof shown in Wiki. I want to know the proof of this theorem using the result of Exercise 8.3.2 in the picture.

Comment: This is a common step in the proof, and I am certain you can find it here. In any case, set $X=g(f(A))$, $Y=g(B)$, and $Z=A$. Then $X\subseteq Y\subseteq Z$ and $g\circ f$ is an injection from $A$ to $Z$.

Comment: Now I think I can prove it. Thank you!!